# SOAPAction header value Exception java web services

Tags: java, web-services

created the web service source using WSDL in netbeans IDE. Then in servlet class generated code to call web service method. I got code like this:

```
private void getSomething() {
com.bla.bla.SomeService service = new com.bla.bla.SomeService();
QName portQName = new QName("http://bla.com/test/services", "SomeServiceSoap");
String req = "<getSomething xmlns="\url\"><a id=\"5\"/></getSomething>";
try {
    Dispatch<Source> dispatch = null;
    dispatch = service.createDispatch(portQName, Source.class, Service.Mode.PAYLOAD);
    Source result = dispatch.invoke(new StreamSource(new StringReader(req)));
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

But when I call this method, I am getting an Exception: `javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server did not recognize the value of HTTP header SOAPAction: .`
How to solve this problem? Any help is appreciated! thanks!

Comment: The format for QName is QName portQName = new QName(URI, ServiceName).I think that there is some problem with the URI "http://bla.com/test/services"

Comment: But I did nothing with that code, NetBeans itself generated it for me using wsdl of webservice.

Answer (score 1):

That error means, though there is some webservice running at the endpoint `http://bla.com/test/services` there is no `operation` is available on that purticular service.

OR

client didnt supply any `operation` to invoke on `SimpleSoapService`

Comment: Thanks! but I get no error If I send that XML using SOAPUI. Everything  in server side where webservice is running is ok. I guess I have to add some piece of code to make my code work. but don't know what to add.

Comment: in soapui you might be selecting the operation. is the http request is same for SOAPUI and your program ?

Comment: yes, they're same. I just copy and paste the printed request from netbeans to SOAPUI and executing.